# nested expression in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-bind-html

I want to create a nested expression in `ng-bind-html`
`eventdetails` is a json object white data gets the input from a return `$stateParams` function

```
<div class="into" ng-bind-html="{{eventdetails.{{data.genre.{{data.event}}.intro}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of the curly braces and use bracket notation to browse an object via variables, `ng-bind-html` is an Angular directive:

```
ng-bind-html="eventdetails[data.genre[data.event]].intro"
```

Comment: must data.genre be in box brackets ?

Comment: yes, else it will look for the property "data" in eventDetails, while you're looking for "data.genre[data.event]]" in eventDetails.